# Laravel 5.4 : Eloquent. Find closest dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have set of users, which contains Date Of Birth.
How i can get closest birthdays using Eloquent ORM without pushing native SQL query into it?

I also have tried next piece of code, which doesn't work correctly:

```
   /**
     * Returns 10 closest birthdays
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function birthdays()
    {
        $carbon = new Carbon();
        $date = "%-" .
        $carbon->month < 10 ? "0{$carbon->month}" : $carbon->month . "-" .
        $carbon->day < 10 ? "0{$carbon->day}" : $carbon->day . "-";

        $birthdays = User::latest('dob')
            ->whereRaw("dob > {$date}")
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();

        return $this->jsonResponse(compact('birthdays'), []);
    }
```

[image: Dates in DB]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this query `$birthdays = User::whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(dob) ')
                        ->orderByRaw('DAYOFYEAR(dob)')
                        ->limit(10)
                        ->get();` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved issue next way:

```
   /**
     * Returns 10 closest birthdays
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function birthdays()
    {

        $date = date('m-d');
        $today_birthdays = User::whereRaw("dob like '%-$date'")
            ->orderBy('dob', 'desc')
            ->get();

        $upcoming_birthdays = User::whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) + 1 <= DAYOFYEAR(dob) and dob not like \'%-' . $date . '\'')
            ->orderBy('dob', 'desc')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();

        return $this->jsonResponse(compact(['upcoming_birthdays', 'today_birthdays']), []);
    }
```

Works like a charm.